# Invalid syntax error when using the drop method in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, syntax-error

I kept getting a syntax error when using the .drop function to delete columns from my dataset. Here's my code:

```
df= ratings.drop(['movieId', 'userId', axis=1])
df
```

movieId and userId are from the dataset ratings which I am trying to drop these two columns.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
df = ratings.drop(['movieId', 'userId'], axis=1) df
```

You placed your ending bracket in wrong place.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(movieId=[1], userId=[2], A=[3], B=[4]))
print(df)

   A  B  movieId  userId
0  3  4        1       2
```

Then

```
df.drop(['movieId', 'userId', axis=1])
```

Yields

> ```
>   File "<ipython-input-1007-977e1363112d>", line 1
>     df.drop(['movieId', 'userId', axis=1])
>                                   ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

```
df.drop(['movieId', 'userId'], axis=1)

   A  B
0  3  4
```

Comment: I tried that, then I got another error saying "labels ['movieId' 'userId'] not contained in axis". But movieId and userId are for sure in the columns

Comment: @CABurns then you probably have white space in your column names.  Try `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`, then try to `drop`.  To see the white space.  `print(df.columns.tolist())` and see if you see anything unexpected.

Comment: It still say "labels ['movieId' 'userId'] not contained in axis". When did the print, it does not display movieId and userId in the output

Comment: @CABurns yes, that is the error.  But what does `print(df.columns.tolist())` say?

Comment: Here's my output from print: ['name', 'gender', 'births', 'year', 'title', 'genres', 'rating']   I don't see movieId and userId

Comment: @CABurns so the error is correct!  Those columns are not in your dataframe.

Comment: @CABurns maybe they are in the index, and you mistakenly thought those were columns.  try to `print(df.index.names)` if those are the index names then try `df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 0):

incase of:

```
price_data.drop[index_to_drop, axis=0, inplace=True]
```

error is in the bracket:
change square bracket to normal bracket:

```
price_data.drop(index_to_drop, axis=0, inplace=True)
```